# Complex Geometry Modeling

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, geometry, object-mode

I am having trouble modeling this metallic chair:

[image]

Should I use noise texture plugged in with Alpha channel of Principle BSDF.

Like this:

[image]

But the problem with this is It also affects the corners/ edges of the chair too.

Or should I try the Boolean modifier.

Also the Corner/Edges of chair is thick around the arms and thin below the arms and above the arms.

Can any tell me what method should I apply?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the alpha method it won't give you thickness, what you can do is import a b&w image, go into *Object > Convert > Trace Image to Grase Pencil*:

[image]

It will give you a new object, select it and *Object > Convert > Bezier Curve*:

[image]

Again it will give you a new object, right click and convert to mesh:

[image]

Then in *Edit* mode select the parts and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> to fill:

[image]

And press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* in order to simplify:

[image]

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude (your object is not flat so you'll have to make it concave before extruding):

[image]